# Is there any packages to directly crop image from url in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any possible way to crop image directly from url in react native?

Tried using this package **react-native-image-crop-picker** but no luck...

```
ImagePicker.openCropper({
  src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  includeBase64: true,
}).then((image) =>  /*  handle */)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 const Crop_image = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: uri.uri,
      width: dimensions.width - 30,
      height: dimensions.height / 3.5,
      maxFiles: 1,
      showCropFrame: false,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log(image.path);
      setCropImg(image.path);
    });

  };
```